# why this file automatically creates itself generated_plugin_registrant.dart

Tags: flutter, dart

everytime i create a project and i run `pubspec.yaml` this file gets generated automatically

```
generated_plugin_registrant.dart
```

[image]

this file was generated as soon as i added my pubspec.yaml from a different project and run pub get what should i do to remove this problem and what does it mean to have this file can i delete it and continue with my project?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`generated_plugin_registrant.dart` is an automatically generated file that is required to compile your Flutter project as a web application:

> This file generated_plugin_registrant. dart exists only to support the web. It exists if Flutter is web-enabled and there is at least one package that has asked for it.

[Source](https://medium.com/better-programming/dont-panic-when-flutter-generates-a-bad-file-for-you-e5e314c2b01#:%7E:text=This%20file%20generated_plugin_registrant.,that%20has%20asked%20for%20it.)

If you're not using Flutter to create a web application, you could drop the web support with the following command:

```
flutter config --no-enable-web
```

Comment: I was just about to write a similar answer. See [this Pull Request on the flutter Github repository](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/41906) as well. It should be included in your `.gitignore` already. PS: the linked Medium article is behind a paywall.

Comment: So can I delete this existing file if I'm building for Android & iOS?

Comment: @Hardik, if your app doesn't support web, you can delete this file.