# Not found: 'dart:html' import 'dart:html'; I don't need dart:html and I also didn't used, but I tried by importing it, but the error isn't going

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart-html

I'm writing a code in which I'm doing registration with firebase. And the data including Profile image is going to firestore. But the issue is I'm getting multiple errors which I'm not able to solve. My app hasn't even run a single time yet. Ione of the error is "import:dart:html" , I've checked all my dart files but I didn't find any unused dart:html import. I'm using import"dart.io" for a term "late File". and I've also tried it by importing dart:html but the error remains the same. I've also tried to remove all the code for ProfileImage but error remains the same there as well. Following are the all files of y code with Errors:

**ERROR**

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 arm in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Invalid depfile: D:\Noum\Data\Uni Data\Codes\Android Studio\Flutter\firebase_flutter_app\.dart_tool\flutter_build\040ba043425f685efe2a35025cf4d63f\kernel_snapshot.d
Invalid depfile: D:\Noum\Data\Uni Data\Codes\Android Studio\Flutter\firebase_flutter_app\.dart_tool\flutter_build\040ba043425f685efe2a35025cf4d63f\kernel_snapshot.d
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-9.0.1/lib/src/storage.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-9.0.1/lib/src/utils.dart:2:8: Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
import 'dart:html';
       ^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.3/lib/js.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js'
export 'dart:js' show allowInterop, allowInteropCaptureThis;
^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/js-0.6.3/lib/js_util.dart:8:1: Error: Not found: 'dart:js_util'
export 'dart:js_util';
^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-9.0.1/lib/src/auth.dart:340:25: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-9.0.1/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    final nextWrapper = allowInterop((firebase_interop.UserJsImpl? user) {
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-9.0.1/lib/src/auth.dart:344:26: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-9.0.1/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
    final errorWrapper = allowInterop((e) => changeController.addError(e));
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-9.0.1/lib/src/auth.dart:374:9: Error: The method 'allowInterop' isn't defined for the class 'Auth'.
 - 'Auth' is from 'package:firebase/src/auth.dart' ('/C:/src/flutter/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/firebase-9.0.1/lib/src/auth.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'allowInterop'.
        allowInterop((firebase_interop.UserJsImpl? user) {
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\flutter.gradle' line: 1035

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
> Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 43s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

**Flutter Doctor**

```
PS C:\Users\Nouma> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19042.1052], locale en-PK)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1.0)
[√] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
[√] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
PS C:\Users\Nouma>
```

**Dependencies**

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.12.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  firebase_auth: ^2.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.3.0
  auth_buttons: ^1.0.1+4
  cloud_firestore: ^2.3.0
  firebase_storage: ^9.0.0
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.4
  firebase_analytics: ^8.1.2
  image_picker: ^0.8.1+3
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.6
```

**Register.dart , this is the file where all code is written**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase/firebase.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart' as route;
import 'package:firebase_flutter_app/ErrorAlertDialog.dart';
import 'package:firebase_flutter_app/StoreHome.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'CustomTextField.dart';
import 'LoadingDialog.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  const Register({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RegisterState createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {
  final TextEditingController _nametextEditingController=TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _emailtextEditingController=TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordtextEditingController=TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _cPasswordEditingController=TextEditingController();
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _globalKey=GlobalKey<FormState>();
  String userImageurl="";
   late File _imagefile;
  final _picker=ImagePicker();
  static final String userID='uid';
  static final String userName='name';
  static final String userEmail='email';
  static final String userAvatar='url';
  static final String userPhotoUrl='photoUrl';
  static final String userCartList='userCart';
  SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=SharedPreferences.getInstance() as SharedPreferences;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    double _screenwidth=MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      child: Container(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize:MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            SizedBox(height: 10.0,),
            InkWell(
              onTap:(){},
              child: CircleAvatar(
                radius: _screenwidth *0.15,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white30,
                // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
                child: Icon(Icons.add_a_photo_outlined,size: _screenwidth *0.15,color: Colors.grey,),
                //backgroundImage: _imagefile==null ? null: FileImage(_imagefile),
                // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
               // child: _imagefile==null ? Icon(Icons.add_a_photo_outlined,size: _screenwidth *0.15,color: Colors.grey,)
               // :null,

              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 8.0,),
            Form(
                key: _globalKey,
                child:Column(
                  children: [
                    CustomTextField(
                    controller: _nametextEditingController,
                      data: Icons.person,
                      hintText: 'Name',
                      isObsecure: false,
                    ),
                    CustomTextField(
                      controller: _emailtextEditingController,
                      data: Icons.email,
                      hintText: 'Email',
                      isObsecure: false,
                    ),
                    CustomTextField(
                      controller: _passwordtextEditingController,
                      data: Icons.password,
                      hintText: 'Password',
                      isObsecure: true,
                    ),
                    CustomTextField(
                      controller: _cPasswordEditingController,
                      data: Icons.password,
                      hintText: 'Confirm Password',
                      isObsecure: true,
                    ),
                  ],
                )
            ),
            RaisedButton(
                onPressed: ()
                {
                //  uploadAndSaveImage();
                },
              color: Colors.blueGrey,
              child: Text('Sign Up',style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white30),),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 30.0,
            ),
            Container(
              height: 4.0,
              width: _screenwidth* 0.8,
              color: Colors.cyan,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15.0,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
   Future<void> _selectAndPickImage() async // ignore: unused_element
  {

    _imagefile = (await _picker.getImage(source: ImageSource.gallery) )as File;
  }

  Future<void> uploadAndSaveImage()async
  {
   // ignore: unnecessary_null_comparison
   if(_imagefile==null)
     {
       showDialog(
           context: context,
           builder:(c)
           {
            return ErrorAlertDialog(message: 'Please Select an Image');

           }
       );
     }
   else
     {
       _passwordtextEditingController.text==_cPasswordEditingController.text
       // ? is an 'if' condition
       //if all these are true we will upload the image
           ? _emailtextEditingController.text.isNotEmpty
           && _passwordtextEditingController.text.isNotEmpty
           && _cPasswordEditingController.text.isNotEmpty
           &&_nametextEditingController.text.isNotEmpty


           ? uploadToStorage()

       //this dialogue is for the upper fields if they remains somehow empty
           :displayDialog('Please fill the empty fields in form...')
           :displayDialog('Password do not match');

     }
  }
  displayDialog(String msg)
  {
    showDialog(context: context,
        builder: (C)
    {
      return ErrorAlertDialog(message: msg);
    }
    );
  }
  uploadToStorage()async
  {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (c){
          return LoadingDialog(mesage: 'Authenticating, Please Wait!...',);
        }

    );
    //unique name to upload it to firestore,and we will use datetime sp it won't repeat again
    String imageFileName=DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString();

    StorageReference storageReference=FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child(imageFileName) as StorageReference;
    var uploadTask=storageReference.put(_imagefile);
    UploadTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot=await uploadTask.future;

    await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL().then((urlimage){
      userImageurl=urlimage as String;

      _registerUser();

    });



  }
  route.FirebaseAuth _auth=route.FirebaseAuth.instance;
  void _registerUser() async
  {
    route.User? userr;
    await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: _emailtextEditingController.text.trim(),
      password: _passwordtextEditingController.text.trim(),
    ).then((auth) {
       userr = auth.user!;
    }).catchError((error) {
      Navigator.pop(context);
      showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (c) {
            return ErrorAlertDialog(message: error.toString(),);
          }
      );
    });
    if (userr != null)
  {
     saveUserInfoToFirestore(userr!).then((value){
     Navigator.pop(context);
     //if the user registration gets successful we will send it to store home
     Route route=MaterialPageRoute(builder: (c)=>StoreHome());
     Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
     });

  }
  }
  Future saveUserInfoToFirestore(route.User firebaseUser) async
  {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').doc(firebaseUser.uid).set({
      'uid':firebaseUser.uid,
      'email':firebaseUser.email,
      'name':_nametextEditingController.text.trim(),
      'url':userImageurl,
    });
    await sharedPreferences.setString('uid', firebaseUser.uid);
    await sharedPreferences.setString(userEmail, firebaseUser.email.toString());
    await sharedPreferences.setString(userName, _nametextEditingController.text.trim());
    await sharedPreferences.setString(userAvatar, userImageurl);
    await sharedPreferences.setStringList(userCartList, ["garbageValue"]);
  }



}
```

**main.dart file : Here I used dart:async for a methode 'Time'**

```
//import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
//import 'package:firebase/firestore.dart';

import 'dart:async';    
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

//import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';

import 'AuthenticationScreen.dart';
import 'StoreHome.dart';

void main() async{
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  //SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=SharedPreferences.getInstance() as SharedPreferences;
  //Firestore firestore=FirebaseFirestore.instance as Firestore;
  // ignore: unnecessary_statements

  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'E-Shop',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}
class SplashScreen extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _splashproperties();
//=>(Fat Arrow is used to replace the braces and return)
}

class _splashproperties extends State<SplashScreen>{
  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    displaySplash();
  }
  displaySplash(){
    FirebaseAuth auth=FirebaseAuth.instance;
    Timer(Duration(seconds: 5), () async{
      if(auth.currentUser!= null)
      {
        Route route=MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=>StoreHome());
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
      }
      else{
        Route route=MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_)=>AuthenticationScreen());
        Navigator.pushReplacement(context, route);
      }
    });
  }


  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material
      (
      child: Container
        (
        decoration: new BoxDecoration(
            gradient: new LinearGradient(colors:[Colors.pink,Colors.lightGreenAccent],
              begin: const FractionalOffset(0.0, 0.0),
              end: const FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0),
              stops: [0.0,1.0],
              tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
            )
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Image.asset('images/xweb.jpg'),
              SizedBox(height: 20.0),
              Text("Number One We Are!!!!!!!",style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white30),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

}
```

Comment: I had the same and this answer helped me: [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65356481/why-this-file-automatically-creates-itself-generated-plugin-registrant-dart/65357096#65357096)

Answer (score 0):

try cleaning packages and run pub get again

```
flutter clean
./gradlew clean
flutter pub get
```

if it didn't work try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55399559/9620401)

Comment: I reinstalled Android Studio, assuming that something might be stuck somewhere in studio memory or cache whatever, then I did flutter clean , pub cache repair , I deleted all the dependencies and again pub get the dependencies , I even tried by deleting pubspec.lock file, but the error didn't move an inch.