# What is `generated_plugin_registrant.dart` in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I see that in my project there's an autogenerated file `generated_plugin_registrant.dart`,

Question: what's that? what's the purpose of it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why this file automatically creates itself generated\_plugin\_registrant.dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65356481/why-this-file-automatically-creates-itself-generated-plugin-registrant-dart)

Comment: As you might guess from the name, it's a piece of generated code that's run at startup to register the plugins. Which plugins are registered is determined automatically by which plugins you included in your pubspec.yaml

Comment: but it is used only on web?

Comment: It is for web support only. If any of your plugins support the web , Flutter will generate it for you automatically.